# findContours crashes in release mode

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to read in an image and find the controus in it. The code works just like I expect if I build in debug mode, but when I try to build in release mode, findContours crashes. I have made sure that I'm linking in the right libs for release, so that doesn't seem to be the problem. Both the imread and thresholds are reading in the data and working like they should. Here's the code I'm trying to run:

```
Mat src;
Mat src_gray;

src = imread(imageIn, 1);

cvtColor(src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
blur(src_gray, src_gray, Size(3, 3));

Mat threshold_output;
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

threshold(src_gray, threshold_output, 100, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
findContours(threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
```

The erorr I get is **Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFF89CE0D6C (ntdll.dll)** Like I said, it works fine in debug mode so I'm not sure what makes it crash in release mode.

Here is the image I'm reading in:

[image: Source Image]

Here's what the image looks like after I find the contours and crop to them in debug mode.

[image: Contours]

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and OpenCV 2.4.9 64bit. The libraries I'm linking in are opencv_core249.lib, opencv_highgui249.lib, opencv_imgproc249.lib, and I'm using the same dll's for the executable. Everything is from the pre-built OpenCV folder \build\x64\vc12.

Comment: Does it really crash within `findContours`? Which compiler do you use?

Comment: Does the input image actually contain any contours (from your visual impression)?

Comment: is your image reading from the correct folder?

Comment: Yes the image is there. It contains contours and if I run within debug mode, it finds them

Comment: And I'm using visual studio 2013

Comment: I saw the exact same thing happen when building my app in **release mode** with OpenCV **debug libraries**. It was easy to fix.